Remove user from "everyone except external users"
I've got an issue where Cove backup requires a Sharepoint backup license because a user is a part of "everyone except external users" which is then a member of "SharepointHome Org Link Viewers". Is there a way to remove the user from the group?

You can't modify the "Everyone except external users" group. But you can create a new Entra ID group and use that instead.
